# visualforce related list for Opportunity Campaign Influence

Tags: visualforce, related-list

Trying to add the Campaign Influence related list to a visualforce page as shown below.

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" id="opportunityPage" tabStyle="Opportunity">
<apex:detail relatedList="false" relatedListHover="true" title="true"/>

<apex:relatedlist list="OpenActivities" id="activityList" />
<apex:relatedlist list="ActivityHistories" id="activityHistoryList" />

<!-- line below fails with 
''CampaignInfluence' is not a valid child relationship name for entity Opportunity' -->  
<apex:relatedList list="CampaignInfluence" id="campaignsList" />

</apex:page>
```

Cannot figure out right value for the campaign influence related list value.  Does anyone know what this should be? or has been able to get this working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should try this. You are just missing a "s".

```
<apex:relatedList list="CampaignInfluences" id="campaignsList" />
```

How did I find it:
I ran this query in my developer console and found all child sObjects of Opportunity

```
List<Schema.ChildRelationship> child = Opportunity.sObjectType.getDescribe().getChildRelationships();
```

Then, I looped over the results to find child side API name of CampaignInfluence sObject.

Comment: Thanks! Tried this but still get the error..

<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" 
           id="opportunityPage"
  tabStyle="Opportunity">

<apex:detail relatedList="false" relatedListHover="true" title="true"/>
<apex:relatedList list="CampaignInfluences" id="campaignsList" />

</apex:page>

Comment: 'CampaignInfluences' is not a valid child relationship name for entity Opportunity

Comment: Well, it works fine when I use it in SOQL. Let me try your code in my org

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be the API version you are using as [CampaignInfluence](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_campaigninfluence.htm):

> Represents the association between a campaign and an opportunity in
>   Customizable Campaign Influence. This object is available in API
>   version 37.0 and later.
>   Note This information applies only to
>   Customizable Campaign Influence and not to Campaign Influence 1.0.

So as well as the name as the relationship name that the_phantom mentions, check the API version that the Visualforce is set to.

Comment: Sounds like a plausible answer.

Comment: Thanks, the visualforce page is using version 42..  I think it has something to do with the way Salesforce internally manages this object which is different and hence causing issues.  But no solution.

Comment: @the_phantom or Keith C were either of you able to get the code working?  Thanks!!

Comment: Starting to think this has something to do with a security setting..  Does anyone know the security required to see the Campaign Influence related list?  Strange that it still fails for system administrators but thinking that maybe even that profile doesn't have the required permission for this object..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<apex:relatedList list="InfluentialCampaigns__r" />
```

Cf Workbench / Menu Info / Standard & Custom Objects / Opportunity /Child Relationships / CampaignInfluence / relationshipName : InfluentialCampaigns__r

PS : Verify your API version